# How do I zip a folder without including all folders in the path?

Tags: command-line, zip

I am attempting to zip a website's home directory but the archive contains the entire path of folders before getting to the one to be zipped. The command `zip -r compressed_data.zip /home/vivek/public_html` results in compressed_data.zip containing home->vivek->public_html rather than simply public_html and its contents.

What switch can I add to the command to omit including all folders in the path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `zip` process will store the full path relative to the current directory, so if you want to have an archive that looks like this:

```
/config
/files
/lib
.htaccess
index.html
```

Then you will need to be in `public_html` to begin with. That said, you can account for this with a one-liner:

```
cd /home/vivek/public_html && zip -r ~/compressed_data.zip . * ; cd -
```

This will change directories, compress the contents, then return you to the home directory.

If you would like to do this as part of a script that is called via a cronjob or other process, create a file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
(cd "/home/vivek/public_html" && zip -r "${dir}/compressed_data.zip" ./*)
```

You can read more about the limits of `zip` from [its manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)

Comment: Thanks a lot @terdon and for the bonus of the bash script. I had gone to the manual page but come away without making any progress.

Comment: @MarkLee all I did was a trivial edit to this answer. The person who answered (and who deserves your thanks) is [matigo](https://askubuntu.com/users/1222991/matigo), not me!

Comment: Thanks @matigo. The system should put your name at the head of the list. I didn't notice it. All praises wrongly given are yours.